# How to generate a list of negative numbers paired with their positive mirrors?

Tags: r, list, function, vector

I was wondering how I could generate a list of paired values that start from `c(-30, 30)`, `c(-29, 29)`, ..., `c(-20, 20)`?

(Each pair has a negative number with its positive mirror).

I tried something like the following with no success:

```
c(-30:-20, 30:20)
```

Comment: lapply(seq(-30,-20), function(x){c(x, abs(x))}) or list(p1= -30:-20, p2 = 30:20)  or data.frame(p1= -30:-20, p2 = 30:20) ?

Comment: Similar to above comment, `lapply(30:20, function(x) c(-x, x))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mapply(c, as.list(20:30), as.list(-20:-30), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can also do `Map(c, as.list(20:30), as.list(-20:-30))`. `Map` is a wrapper to `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY` set to FALSE.